# Calculations based on selected Checkbox

Tags: vb.net

I have 4 Checkboxes and a Label.
Each checkbox represents an item.
The label on the other hand will display the price of the item that has been checked.

Now, I want to know the code for displaying the calculation in the label. For example if checkbox 1 and checkbox 2 are banana and apple respectively, and the prices are $2 and $3 repectively, and they are both checked then the label will display 2+3 = $5.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add a [mcve] detailing your code. List the errors, if any, why this code is not working for you and what you want it to do.

Comment: You want to know the code for adding two values?  You just wrote it... It's the `+` operator.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that you have a variable `amount`.
When a `Checkbox`( assign a name for the checkbox. Here I'll assume it's `item`) is clicked, you have to update the variable `amount` and set the value of this to the `Label`.

You can use `OnClick()`method and check the `Checked` status  to perform this. Since you have not written any code, I'd suggest you try it on your own.